# How to resollve spring temlateInput Exception in Java?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using spring boot,thymleaf, spring MVC, gradlebuild tool. I want to implement spring mail with thymleaf template attachment. When I am calling web service(restful) inside this method called for send email and this method, I am calling a spring template engine to generate a thymleaf template to send in email attachment.

**For more clarification I am attaching one flow structure.**

[image]

**RestController**

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/completeBatchUpload")
public Map<String,String>completeBatchShipmentUpload() throws Exception {

Map<String, String> resp = new HashMap<>();
 String s = emailService.sendmail();

//----some code here based on result of emailService.sendmail method.----
 return resp;    
}
```

**EmailService.java**

```
public String sendmail(){
     try {
        MimeMessage message = javaMail.createMimeMessage();

         try {
          MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
          helper.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
          helper.setTo(new InternetAddress("xyz@gmail.com"));
          helper.setSubject("subject here");                                                  helper.setText(attachmentUtile.buildContentUsingTemplate();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new MailParseException(e);
                }

                javaMail.send(message);
            }
    }
```

---

```
@Service
public class AttachmentUtile {

    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @Autowired
    public AttachmentUtile (SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        this.templateEngine = templateEngine;
    }

    public String buildContentUsingTemplate(List<Map<String, String>>     templateContent, String recipientName) {
        final Context ctx = new Context();
        ctx.setVariable("recipientName", "ritesh");
        String s = templateEngine.process("send", ctx);
        return s;

    }
}
```

---

**send.html**

Sending Email with Thymeleaf HTML Template Example

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>



<!-- use the font -->
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 48px;
    }
</style>
```

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#78ab46" style="padding: 40px 0 30px 0;">
            <p>RITESH CHOUDAHRY</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#eaeaea" style="padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;">
            <p>Dear ${recipientName},</p>
            <p>Sending Email using Spring Boot with <b>Thymeleaf template !!!</b></p>
            <p>Thanks</p>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

---

**ThymleafConfiuration file**

```
@Configuration
public class ThymLeafConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver  htmlTemplateResolver(){ 
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(StandardTemplateModeHandlers.HTML5.getTemplateModeName());
        emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        return emailTemplateResolver;
    }
```

---

**Project folder Structure**

**[image: project folder structure]**

**I am getting below exception:**

[image]

I have seen one link in stackoverflow [Error resolving template “login” spring boot, thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096100/error-resolving-template-login-spring-boot-thymeleaf), But still I am not able to solve my problem. If anybosy have have idea please share. Thanks in advance. If any query required please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have exactly the same problem as in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096100/error-resolving-template-login-spring-boot-thymeleaf) you cite.

From your project structure one can tell that path to template is `classpath:/templates/send.thml` as you put your template in resources folder. Later it will land added to your jar/war.

At the same time you configure your prefix to

```
emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
```

which in web app will be treated as folder in the applicaton root directory (not /WEB-INF/classes where the web app classpath resides), in jar bootable app this path will be considered relative to base folder (one you have used to run your app).

You should update the line to

```
emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
```

The `classpath:` prefix gives Spring `ResourceResolver` a hint that your template is application classpath resource (should be searched for with `ClassLoader.getResource()`).

Comment: thanks a lot . Now my problem is solved from your code. Please up vote this question for help to others.